# Java int[] table print reverse numbers

Tags: java

I have been started coding Java and wan't to find solution for this:

I have table for this:

```
int nmb[ ] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

And it should output it the numbers reserve from 10 to 1

What i have tested so far haven't worked

```
int nmb[ ] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}; 

    for(int i=10; i >= 1; i--)
        nmb[i]=i*2;

    for(int i=10; i >= 1; i--)
        System.out.println(nmb[i]);
```

Also the code should print out the 5th number in the string.

I will be really thankfully if you help me fix this.

Comment: What string? What is your problem? Which error message is shown or what is the "unwanted" behaviour?

Comment: why do you do this? for(int i=10; i >= 1; i--)
        nmb[i]=i*2; and what string are you talking about?

Comment: I mean that it should print the 5th number from this `int nmb[ ] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};`

Comment: For the futur, when you have a code generating an exception (her you should get an out of bounds Exception), it is good to add it to the question (at least mention it ...).

Answer (score 5):

The following `for` loop should work:

```
for (int i=nmb.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    System.out.println(nmb[i]);
```

Java arrays are indexable from *zero* until the length of the array minus one.

Comment: Thanks this worked!

Do you know ow can i print the 5th number from this `int nmb[ ] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};`

Comment: The newbie lesson is that array indices in Java start from 0 and go up to the length of the array minus 1, which in reverse is length of the array minus 1 down to zero;  OP had been trying to go from length of array (not minus 1) down to 1.

Comment: ...so the fifth number is at `nmb[4]`.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Thanks for that comment.  I was busy on lesson two, how to iterate lists in Java 7 :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Java, arrays are a collection of similar type of elements.Arrays are index based data structure where first element is stored at index `0`, Means first element in array would be accessed as `array[0]` where as last element can be accessed as `array[size-1]`

To reverse the elements you can loop on indexes in reverse order the way shown by `Tim Biegeleisen` exaclty does the same.

If you are more curious to learn the advanced concepts then we can use the `sort` method of `Arrays` or `Collections` classes to get the desired output for you. Please read below to find out the alternate way to get elements in reversed order.

In java 8 using the `Comparator.reverseOrder()` with `Stream` we can easily reverse the order. For e.g.

```
System.out.println("Reversing with Java 8 ");
    Integer []numerals= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        Arrays.stream(numerals)
                .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you are still using Java 6 then we can achive the same using `Collections.reverseOrder()` as shown below

```
 System.out.println("Reversing with Java 6 ");
   Integer []numerals= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    Arrays.sort(numerals,Collections.reverseOrder());
      for(Integer i=0;i<numerals.length;i++) {
          System.out.println(numerals[i]);
      }
```

You can also use the `advance-for-loop` as shown below

```
   System.out.println("Reversing with Java 6 Advanced for loop  ");
     Integer []numerals= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        Arrays.sort(numerals,Collections.reverseOrder());
          for(Integer number :numerals) {
              System.out.println(number);
          }
```

Comment: I am pretty sure OP won't understand any of these since he don't now yet that an array is 0-based index... you should add some explanation to be correct.

Comment: Surely, I missed that. I will edit the post to add some description.

Answer (score -1):

Please find attached code : its prints numbers in reverse order , and prints 5th place element as string.
public class ReverseNumber {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        int nmb[ ] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}; 
        int []newArray = new int[nmb.length]; 
        int arrayLength = newArray.length ;
        int i,j;
        for(i=0,j=arrayLength-1;i<arrayLength & j >=0;j--, i++)
            newArray[j]=nmb[i];

        System.out.println("Reverse Number : ");
        for (i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
            //nmb[i]=newArray[i];
            System.out.println(newArray[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("Number present at fifth position : "+Integer.toString(nmb[4]));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: @Sami Pietilä : if solution is working for you .. Pleas mark it as accept.